# What's an ESAT as filmed in "Top Gun: Maverick"

Tags: radio-communications, flight-tracking, aviation-in-fiction

This is an image from the movie [Top Gun: Maverick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gun:_Maverick)

The scene in question is between 01:48:20 - 01:48:34

In the movie they're calling this device an ESAT, which is sending some signal which is visible on their radar

Now, I don't see any marker on this device which is telling me that this is pointing to "GPS", which most probably is a GPS transmitter for communicating their location, not GPS receiver

And the other options are "VOICE", "406 BCN", and "TRIPLE BCN"

From these options, I understand this is some sort of device for communication based on different situations

What is this device called generally ? Something that I can Google and read about because I don't see anything named ESAT on Google.

And, what are those other 2 BCN options ? Can't find anything about them either on Google.

[image]

Comment: ESAT probably have something to do with SARSAT and Satellite Aided Tracking. This dial is typical of the AN/PRC series survival ratios. Military pilots carry those on every flight so eventually someone would identify this one. (Maybe this is PRC-125 but I can not find any pictures of it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you google the AN/PRC-90 you’ll get very close.  I am guessing this is either (a) a more modernized replacement, or (b) more likely, a “dramatized version” of the PRC-90 with dramatized features.

As for double/triple beacons… There are actually 3 frequencies set aside specifically for emergency, ELT, and EPIRB applications:  121.5 MHz, 243 MHz, and 406 MHz.  (Hence the “406 BCN” label on the knob.)  A device could transmit a “civilian intended” beacon on 121.5, a “military intended” beacon on 243, or a GPS location encoded beacon on 406.

I was an Army officer in special operations *many* years ago and the appearance, features, and functionality of almost everything we carried ended up quite dramatized for movies.

Comment: Hollywood makes stuff up? I'm _shocked_! Thank you for your service.